# How to sort Pandas Dataframe based on Parent/Child IDs?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, indexing

I have a dataframe of event logs that contain a column with the previous event's ID, but they are not in sequential order and I'd like to make it so. If we take the following dataframe of Event names, IDs, and previous event IDs and shuffle it, we get:

```
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np
  df = pd.DataFrame(
      {
          'Event_name': ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'Fifth', 'Sixth', 'Seventh', 'Eigth', 'Ninth', 'Tenth'],
          'Event_Ids': ['QXT364', 'YKD306', 'GJJ60', 'RSK547', 'GNN259', 'DKW368', 'OAN385', 'PGF213', 'NGJ285', 'OLG594'],
          'Previous_Event_Ids': [np.nan,'QXT364', 'YKD306', 'GJJ60', 'RSK547', 'GNN259', 'DKW368', 'OAN385', 'PGF213', 'NGJ285']
    }
  )
df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

It outputs:

```
     Event_name Event_Ids Previous_Event_Ids
0     Fourth    RSK547              GJJ60
1      Eigth    PGF213             OAN385
2      First    QXT364                NaN
3      Third     GJJ60             YKD306
4      Fifth    GNN259             RSK547
5      Sixth    DKW368             GNN259
6    Seventh    OAN385             DKW368
7      Ninth    NGJ285             PGF213
8     Second    YKD306             QXT364
9      Tenth    OLG594             NGJ285
```

What code could be used to sort this so that the DataFrame ends up like this?

```
  Event_name Event_Ids Previous_Event_Ids
0      First    QXT364                NaN
1     Second    YKD306             QXT364
2      Third     GJJ60             YKD306
3     Fourth    RSK547              GJJ60
4      Fifth    GNN259             RSK547
5      Sixth    DKW368             GNN259
6    Seventh    OAN385             DKW368
7      Eigth    PGF213             OAN385
8      Ninth    NGJ285             PGF213
9      Tenth    OLG594             NGJ285
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a `dict` with mapping string values to `int`, then sort on integer values:

```
In [301]: vars_map = {'First': 1, 'Second': 2, 'Third': 3, 'Fourth':4, 'Fifth':5, 'Sixth':6, 'Seventh': 7, 'Eigth':8, 'Ninth':9, 'Tenth':10}

In [305]: df1 = df.assign(vals=df.Event_name.map(vars_map)).sort_values('vals').drop('vals', 1)

In [306]: df1
Out[306]: 
  Event_name Event_Ids Previous_Event_Ids
1      First    QXT364                NaN
3     Second    YKD306             QXT364
5      Third     GJJ60             YKD306
7     Fourth    RSK547              GJJ60
9      Fifth    GNN259             RSK547
2      Sixth    DKW368             GNN259
8    Seventh    OAN385             DKW368
0      Eigth    PGF213             OAN385
6      Ninth    NGJ285             PGF213
4      Tenth    OLG594             NGJ285
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without a `dict` map? For example, if we don't know that `First` is the first value, `Second` is the second value, etc.

Comment: I guess `dict` is imperative here. Otherwise there's no way to tell Python to sort it in the way you want. Essentially, `First` can be any value which is less than `Second` and so on.

Comment: Could we use a `for` loop to find matching pairs of `Event_Ids` and `Previous_Event_Ids`, and then sort with the `NaN` at the top?

Comment: It seems possible actually.. you only need to know the first.. and nan is the identifier

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out with the following code:

```
# Step 1: Initialize the dictionary
var_map = dict.fromkeys(df.index.values)

# Step 2: Find our start value, NaN
nanLoc,_ = np.where(df.isna())

# Step 3: Put NaN in the first slot of the dictionary
var_map[0] = df.loc[nanLoc].values.tolist()[0]

# Step 4: Iterate through the dataframe
for x in df.index.values[:-1]:
    key = var_map[x][1]
    var_map[x+1] = df.loc[df['Previous_Event_Ids'] == key].values.tolist()[0]

#Step 5: Turn the dictionary into a DataFrame
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(var_map, orient='index', columns=['Event_name', 'Event_Ids', 'Previous_Event_Ids'])
print(df2)
```